# Nuxt taking more than 1 hours to Build

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, ag-grid-vue

> I'm building a Nuxt application. I've done some research but found no definitive solution.

```
Step 6/8 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in e5d36d6e86fe
Removing intermediate container e5d36d6e86fe
 ---> f655ef5cccc2
Step 7/8 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in f6445150af4c

> nuxt build

ℹ Production build
ℹ Bundling for server and client side
ℹ Target: server
ℹ Using components loader to optimize imports
ℹ Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md
✔ Builder initialized
✔ Nuxt files generated
ℹ Warming up worker pools
✔ Worker pools ready
ℹ Compiling Client
✔ Client: Compiled successfully in 1.00h
ℹ Compiling Server
✔ Server: Compiled successfully in 1.81m
```

Comment: Where are you running the build? (AWS, local dev environment, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Config

There are several experimental ways of improving build speed.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#parallel

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#cache

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#hardsource

```
build: {
    // standalone: true,
    analyze: false,
    parallel: true,
    cache: true,
    hardSource: false,
    splitChunks: {
      layouts: false,
      pages: false,
      components: false,
    },
    html: {
      minify: {
        minifyCSS: false,
        minifyJS: false
      }
    },
    loaders: {
      vue: {
        prettify: false
      }
    },
    transpile: ["@coreui/vue", "@coreui/utils", "@ag-grid-community/vue"],
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? "source-map" : "inline-source-map";
      }
    }
  }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14


COPY package*.json ./tmp/
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

#COPY package*.json ./
#RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm run build
# RUN npm run generate

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```